# A Theory of 3-connected graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Does anybody in here know how to get hold of this article:

"Tutte, W.T., A Theory of 3-connected graphs, Indag. Math. 23 (1961) 441-455"

or have it on paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the volume "Selected Papers of W.T. Tutte" published by the Charles Babbage Research Centre about 20 years ago.

(Strangely the reference is slightly different, but the title and page numbers are identical.)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Indagationes Mathematicae also has a different title, Proceedings of the Royal Dutch Academy of Sciences.  So some libraries have it under "Koninklijke Nederlandse Akademie van Wetenschappen" instead of Indagationes.  To make matters worse, the same volume of the journal will have different volume numbers under the two titles.  This is one situation where the help of a competent librarian may save you a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 2):

I found it in Science Direct Web Site:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1385725861500455